# Suppress the message "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30..."

Tags: php, timeout, fatal-error

I'm using `register_shutdown()` to provide show a page if upload takes a long time causing a PHP timeout. I really don't need to show the fatal error to the user, how can hide that message?

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` and/or `ini_set('display_errors',0);` not good enough? You shouldn't be showing errors in a production environment anyway...

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks i'm going to try. Nope i was thinking that fatal error are always shown even in production, as default host setting. Thanks

Comment: @DaveRandom Why would you turn error reporting off completely?  Your application should still track and log errors when they happen, just don't display details of the error to the user.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry I know, but I suggested both approaches (with an and/**or**) so the OP can decide which way to go, and one can assume that this particular OP has a modicum of common sense since he has a decent reputation :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to set the [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directive in your `php.ini` to off on your production machine.  Alternatively if your script doesn't have any fatal errors beyond the timeout issue you may use [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to turn off displaying errors at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

To hide the error message, you can use `error_reporting(E_NONE)` to suppress all error messages.

Or, you can just do a `ini_set('display_errors','0');` to hide the error messages from being displayed, and log them.